# read more toogle function button disappears after click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a javascript function at my wordpress blog. The "read more" link from wordpress loads the hidden text at the same page.
It works fine. If you see the hidden text there is a button called "close" to hide the text again, but if I click on this button the button to open the text again it disappears. 
Of course,I would like to see the "read more" button again so that the user can open and close the hidden text as often as he wants to.

PHP code

```
<?php 
function pobo_rmi_oninit(){
    if(!is_admin()){
            $pluginUrl = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);
            wp_register_script(
                'pobo_rmi', 
                $pluginUrl . "js/pobo_rmi.js",
                array('jquery'));
            wp_enqueue_script('pobo_rmi');
    }
}
add_action('init', pobo_rmi_oninit); 
function pobo_rmi_morelink_filter($link){
    global $post;
    $my_id = $post->ID;
        $post_object= get_post($my_id);
        $content = $post_object->post_content;
        $debris = explode('<!--more-->', $content);
    $link.='</p><div class="readmoreinline">'.$debris[1].'</div><a class="close">close</a>';
    return $link;
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link', pobo_rmi_morelink_filter, 999);?>
```

javascript Code:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('document').ready(function(){
    $j('.readmoreinline').hide();
    $j('.close').hide();
    $j('.more-link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $j(this).empty().parent().next('.readmoreinline').show();
        $j('.close').show(); 

            $j('.close').click(function(e){
    $j('.readmoreinline').hide();
    $j('.close').hide();
    });
    });

});
```

can someone help me? thanks a lot! 
regards
flo

Comment: Have you tried adding `$j('.more-link').show();` when the `close` button is clicked?

Comment: like this: `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j('document').ready(function(){
 $j('.readmoreinline').hide();
 $j('.close').hide();
 
 $j('.more-link').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $j(this).empty().parent().next('.readmoreinline').show();
  $j('.close').show(); 
  
   $j('.close').click(function(e){
 $j('.readmoreinline').hide();
 $j('.close').hide();
  $j('.more-link').show();
 });
 });

});` It didn´t work :-(